# Unable to generate OAuth 2.0 Access Token from Office365 via JavaScript

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, office365, access-token

I'm trying to pull an access token from Office365's `/token` identity platform endpoint via [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0). I have my app registered, the client ID & secret, etc...

I can make the POST request in Postman and receive the access token without issue:
[image]

However, when I try the POST request via JavaScript (by way of Google Apps Script), I receive an error message: `AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'`

I've already Google'd this error and found a bunch of different solutions, and have tried implementing them to no avail. I imagine this has to do with the URL encoding, but cannot figure it out.

**Code:**

```
function getO365() {
  // POST Request (To get Access Token)
  var tenantID = 'longstringhere'
  var appID = 'longstringhere'
  var appSecret = 'longstringhere'
  var graphScore = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

  var url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

  var data = {
    'client_id': appID,
    'scope': graphScore,
    'client_secret': appSecret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  };

  var postOptions = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': data,
    'redirect': 'follow'
  };

  var authToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, postOptions);

}
```

The only real difference between my code and the JavaScript Fetch code I pulled off of Postman is:

```
var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "longstringhere");
urlencoded.append("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "longstringhere");
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
```

When I try to use `URLSearchParams` in Google Apps Script, I keep getting this error: `ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read documentation of urlfetch. There is no `option` with key `body`.

Comment: Bless you @TheMaster. Just had to change it to 'payload', and it works like a charm.

Comment: Good to know. Question is question and answer is answer. Don't change question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by changing 'body' to 'payload' for UrlFetchApp per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). Edited code to reflect the change. Credit to [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) for pointing out my mistake.

```
'payload': data,//from   'body': data,
```